# Linux/bash: How to get interface's IPv6 address?

Tags: linux, bash, ipv6

What command can I use to get IPv6 address of an interface in a script?

Update: Output of sed from one of answers.

```
$ ip -6 addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::224:d7ff:fed0:4f5c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The other:

```
$ ip addr show dev eth0 | sed -e's/^.*inet6 \([^ ]*\)\/.*$/\1/;t;d'
$ ip addr show dev eth0
  2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
  link/ether f0:de:f1:7b:e9:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Which IPv6 addresses? Your interfaces' IPv6 addresses?

Comment: Yes, edited, thx.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use:

```
ip -6 addr
```

It will return all the IPv6 adresses you have configured.

Answer (score 16):

There are lots of ways you could do this.

Here is one:

```
ip addr show dev eth0 | sed -e's/^.*inet6 \([^ ]*\)\/.*$/\1/;t;d'
```

It is similar to Robert's answer, except strips out the address only.

Answer (score 2):

If you're under Linux you also can parse:
`/proc/net/if_inet6`

First column is the full IPv6 without colons.
Sixth column is the interface name.

Here a rather lengthy not optimized version (I only now the basics of awk)
Maybe python/perl is a better choice.

```
for i in "$(grep enp0s25 /proc/net/if_inet6)"; do
    echo "$i" | awk '{
        split($1, _, "[0-9a-f]{,4}", seps)
        joined = sep = ""
        for (i=1; i in seps; i++) {
            joined = joined sep seps[i]
            sep = ":"
        }
        print joined
    }'
done
```

If you have GNU awk (gawk) this can be shortened to:

```
for i in "$(grep enp0s25 /proc/net/if_inet6)"; do
    echo "$i" | gawk '@include "join"
    {
        split($1, _, "[0-9a-f]{,4}", seps)
        print join(seps, 1, length(seps), ":")
    }'
done
```

You may put it in a {ba,z,}sh function to use it later.

Comment: I get this error when using the first code
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,

Answer (score 1):

The other approaches mentioned here **WILL FAIL** if the IF is not named `eth0`. And in the world of SystemD, IF names are far from predictable as [IF naming conventions have changed drastically](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/)

My approach instead finds & extracts the Global Unicast Address- whatever the IF might be named. The IPv6 address could be configured for `wlan0`- or any other name- and my bash snippet will successfully extract and expand it as a variable in a config file requiring the listening address to be specified.

```
IPV6GLOBALUNICAST="$(ip -6 addr|awk '{print $2}'|grep -P '^(?!fe80)[[:alnum:]]{4}:.*/64'|cut -d '/' -f1)"
```

Paste below onto the CLI of a host with an IPv6 address configured to test it:

```
ip -6 addr|awk '{print $2}'|grep -P '^(?!fe80)[[:alnum:]]{4}:.*/64'|cut -d '/' -f1
```

I'm using this with great success and hasn't failed in any circumstances to date.  HTH- Terrence Houlahan